# Bot Framework: Bot responds with "undefined"

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a simple chatbot which takes the user's name and replies asking how it can help them. It works fine in the emulator and webchat but when I tried that as an android app via DirectLine I'm getting an additional prompt which is just empty. So I put some code to log the bot's conversation and I found that the bot is sending a message "undefined" along with the prompt I programmed it to send.

**My Code sample**

```
bot.dialog('/', new builder.IntentDialog()
    .matchesAny([/hi/i], [
        function (session) {
            session.send('Hi, I am a chatbot.');
            session.beginDialog('/step2')
        },
        bot.dialog('/step2', [
            function (session) {
                builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What is your name?');
            },
            function (session, args, next) {
                session.send('Hello, ' + args.response + '. How may I help you today?');
                name = args.response;
                session.endConversation();
            }
        ])
    ]));
```

When I put in some middleware logging, I got the following output:

> USER: Hi
>
> BOT: Hi, I am a chatbot.
>
> BOT: What is your name?
>
> USER: Bob
>
> BOT: Hello, Bob. How may I help you today?
>
> BOT: undefined

Even my node console shows that 2 messages are sent at the end instead of just one

```
ChatConnector: message received.
UniversalBot("*") routing "Anish" from "emulator"
Library("BotBuilder").findRoutes() explanation:
        ActiveDialog(0.5)
..BotBuilder:prompt-text - Prompt.returning(Anish)
..BotBuilder:prompt-text - Session.endDialogWithResult()
./step2 - waterfall() step 2 of 2
./step2 - Session.send()
./step2 - Session.endConversation()
Session.sendBatch() sending 2 message(s)
```

Why is that undefined message being sent? How can I stop it?

Comment: What happens in you remove the `Session.endConversation()`?

Comment: @EzequielJadib wow, that worked. Why is `Session.endconversation()` causing this?

Comment: But if I don't use `session.endconversation()`, the bot is going in loop and asking me what my name is when I reply to "how may I help you"

Comment: Actually, you can send the message in the endConversation method (one of the accepted parameters is the text); however then you will see the same behavior, once you reply it will start the conversation with the same question

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following line

```
 session.send('Hello, ' + args.response + '. How may I help you today?');
```

And replace the `Session.endConversation()` call with:

```
Session.endConversation('Hello, ' + args.response + '. How may I help you today?');
```

Alternatively, you can just remove the `Session.endConversation()` call as I mentioned in the comments

You can also check the [End of Conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-global-handlers#end-a-conversation) documentation topic.

Comment: Nope, it's still sending "undefined".

Comment: Mmmm strange, anyways. I updated the response to also include what I mentioned in the comments